# Discussion list web part is different from the default web part

Tags: web-part, discussion-board, app-part, categories

I am working on creating a discussion board/community site for my company's SharePoint site. Everything works perfectly, but I have run into a few stylistic issues that I cannot figure out.

I created a new community site and it has the default home page that has a web part for the Discussion list. My issue is that when I add a web part for the same discussion list anywhere else, the two do not look the same and they are not the same size.

[image]

The top is the default web part and it displays a bar with the likes and replies, and beneath the post it indicates what category the posts are in. As you can see, the web/app part I added does not display these things and I cannot figure out how to get them to show. Does anyone know how to do this?

On a less important note, does anyone know why the default app part is less wide  than the one I created? Both are set to fit the content area. It's really bothering me because I want to add a Categories web part but I want everything to be the same size (while set to fit the area, not a defined size).

**Edit - fixed part of the issue**

So the issue of displaying the likes/replies bar in a web part ended up being fixed by changing the settings. Everything was actually correct by default when I added the web part, but for some reason it just wasn't showing. When I edited the Disussions List (actual list and not the web part) and under rating settings turned Allow Rating off and on again and switched between likes and stars, the List showed the replies/likes bar. Then I edited the web part and when I changed the view and then changed it back the replies/likes bar showed up. Everything was set correctly to begin with, it just wasn't working for some reason. Resetting the settings seemed to fix the issue.

Still no idea why the sizes are different though.

Comment: I also noticed a similar issue - Like option was not available in blogs and discussions detail page. I have reset the like and rating settings in order to fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the page and then edit the web part in question and you can change the view. You can select one of the different views available, or create one that matches what you want!

Comment: I've already tried doing that, and the two web parts in the image both have the every setting exactly the same and show the same views. I've tried switching to all other views, but none of the views show the likes/replies bar, which is present both in the web part on a page AND in the actual Discussions List

Answer (score 0):

Edit the webpart and select **subject** view from the dropdown.
[image]